# Add check-box to remove from database in for each loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP at the moment, started a practice project to make a todo list.
The list allows the user to enter data into the database with an input field, and uses a while and foreach loop to display the data from the database.

I want to add a check-box to each item displayed that allows the user to check what items on the list they'd like to remove, and for the check-box to have a value corresponding to the id column of the item, then I'll add a submit button that will clear the checked items.

The database table I'm using has two columns an auto increment id column, and a description column.

Here's the loop:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM list_data;";
$list = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $list->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($row as $list_item) {
        echo "<td>" . $list_item . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";

endwhile;

?>
```

I tried this:

```
foreach ($row as $id => $description) {
    echo "<td>" . $id . $description . "</td>";
}
```

But for soeme reason this returns the column name, and the values like so:
id1 descriptionTodo List Item Number One.
id2 descriptionTodo List Item Number Two.
id3 descriptionTodo List Item Number Three.
id5 descriptionTodo List Item Number Four.

Can anyone set me on the right path?
I've got the project uploaded onto github if anyone wants to see the whole lot.
Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: There's no checkbox element in your code? Also try using `fetch_assoc` instead.

Comment: You're using `MYSQLI_ASSOC` which means that `$list_item` will be `[ 'id' => 1, 'description' => '....' ]`. Use `foreach ( $row as $colname => $value )` instead.

Comment: Yeah I haven't added the checkbox element yet, but I cant get the id and description separate for me to use the id value variable as the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using foreach actually , I would just do this :

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM list_data;";
$list = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $list->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
echo "<tr>";

echo"<td><input type='checkbox' value='".$row['id']."'</td>      <td>".$row['description']."</td>";

echo "</tr>";

endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to change the foreach loop, when I don't need it! This makes so much sense now.